# Evaluating the limit of an expression - valid argument?

Tags: limits

I'm always a bit unsure of the validity of the steps I take when evaluating limits. This particular examples evokes the standard results that $\frac{k^n}{n^2}$ tends to infinity as n tends to infinity for $k>1$ and then that if a sequence $a_n$ tends to infinity then $\frac{1}{a_n}$ tends to 0 as n tends to infinity. Here is my full working:

[image]

Are there any issues with my argument here? If so I would greatly appreciate some advice on how better to think about these kinds of problems. Thanks.

Comment: you are wrong!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the clearest argument is to factor out the dominant term from the numerator and denominator, respectively:
$$
\frac{16n^2+7}{3^n+2} = \frac{n^2}{3^n} \cdot \frac{16 + \frac{3}{n^2}}{1+\frac{2}{3^n}}
\to 0 \cdot \frac{16+0}{1+2\cdot 0} = 0,
\qquad
n\to\infty
.
$$
Note that the whole expression is rewritten with equality until the last step (i.e. no terms vanish mysteriously in the middle of the computation), and then all limits are taken at the same time. This makes it clear which standard limits you're using, and which limit laws that are being used to combine them.

Comment: That's a very useful tip. I agree this is a very clear way to structure the argument. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is not obviously correct; the second equality is not convincing. You have attempted to use "limit of quotient is quotient of limits" when the denominator has a limit of $\infty$.

To fix this, simply multiply top and bottom by $3^{-n}$ first.

---

Original answer:

I would instead use that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits: $$\frac{16n^2+7}{3^n + 2} = \frac{16n^2}{3^n+2} + \frac{7}{3^n+2}$$

The limit of this expression is $$16 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{ 3^n + 2} + \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{7}{3^n+2}$$

That last term is, of course, $0$.

The first term is $0$, as we see by multiplying top and bottom by $3^{-n}$ and using "limit of quotient is quotient of limits".

Comment: Surely "limit of quotient is quotient of limits" is what I've used in the second equality. The limit of the numerator evaluates to 16 and the limit of the denominator evaluates to infinity, no?

Comment: Oh right. I understand what you did now. Heuristically you're right, and depending on what form of "limit of quotients is quotient of limits" you're using, you're rigorously right. I much prefer to avoid having explicit expressions of the form $\frac{1}{\infty}$, though. I multiplied top and bottom by $3^{-n}$ to ensure that the denominator tended to a finite nonzero quantity.

Comment: I've edited in a fix.